# Looping through files in folder with Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have been trying to write excel macro that loops through files in folder returns names of the files. I have been googling and testing but I'm unable to make it work. This is the code:

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()

   Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
   Set MySource = MyObj.GetFolder("c:\test\")
   For Each file In MySource.Files
      MsgBox file
   Next file

End Sub
```

I'm getting this error:

> Run-time error '91':
>
> Object Variable or with block variable not set.

Excel file is named `test.xlsm`. There are 3 files in the folder: `test01.txt`, `test02.txt`, `test03.txt`. I'm using windows 7, 64 bit.

Comment: `MyObj` is `Nothing` you didn't define it.

Comment: Dim MyObj As Object or I need to use set command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to `Set MyObj` for example

```
Dim MyObj As Object
Set MyObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

otherwise `MyObj` is a empty variable and returns `Nothing`.

Comment: Another option would be to reference FSO in VBA and set `MyObj` to that (i.e. `Dim MyObj As New FileSystemObject`)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Dir` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function)?

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim FileName AS String

    FileName = Dir("c:\test\*") 'Any file in the folder

    While Len(FileName) > 0
        MsgBox FileName 'Say the file's name
        FileName = Dir() 'Get next item that matches the filter
    Wend
End Sub
```